# How to run an R script from powershell and have all printed output written to file?

Tags: r

I have an R script with some print statements throughout. I start it from powershell with `Rscript "myscript.R"`

The print statements within the R script appear in the powershell terminal. How can I have them write to a file without having the manually edit the R script?

Comment: You can use `sink()` ... read the documentation.

Comment: @jogo Thanks, I knew of sink(). I adjusted the question slightly

Comment: What about redirecting standard output (and eventually standard error) to a file?

Comment: @FabioMarroni if it results in the content that would be printed to the powershell terminal going to a file? That is what i'm after

Comment: Then Rscript "myscript.R" > myfile.txt to print standard output alone, or Rscript "myscript.R" > myfile.txt 2>&1 to print both standard output and standard error.